# Asynchronous websocket mechanism which pretend to be synchronous

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am not looking specific answer, just an idea or a tip.
I have following problem:

Android application is a client for web service. It has a thread, which sends events (XML form with request ID) through http protocol and for every request server sends confirmation, that he understand message right with granted event ID - server is a synchronizer for few clients. I want use websocket protocol to send events through websocket too but it is a little bit tricky - instead of http, I don't expect to get response for every request. Moreover, incoming websocket messages is parsed in other thread. Primary mechanism it's a little bit overgrown and I don't want to write everything from scratch.

I want to make this asynchronous websocket mechanism to pretend to be synchronous.
There is my idea for now - after send event through websocket I will wait no more for e.g 5 seconds for response which will processed in other thread (it's came as XML) and regarding too request ID it will notify proper paused thread. I worry Condition.await() and condition.signal isn't the best idea, what do you think?

According to this problem, I've realized that I have problems with project this kind of mechanism. Do you have an idea, where can I find information about good pattern and tips which good to now to avoid bad approach? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between websocket and HTTP requests is the lack of HTTP headers when a message comes in. In websocket, you have a heartbeat that keeps the connection alive and allows full duplex communication, and then you have pure payloads. It's your job to find which message headers you will use to route the requests properly in your server/client.

So, that doesn't stop you from communicating in a request/response manner by simply writing to the output stream right after receiving. I suggest you take a look at the RFC

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455

If you're a little more visual, this slideshow can help:

http://www.slideshare.net/sergialmar/websockets-with-spring-4

Or if you want some more serious implementations as an example, take a look at spring's docs:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html

Comment: Thank you for give me few good information about Websocket - I have understood it wrong.
Unfortunately I can't change way how server reacts on my request, so I suppose I don't have influence if server sends response as separated request, or it is connected in any way. The main problem with linking request and response is to compare requestID, what I can check before I parse request to XML form, and after I unparse response from XML form.
It is a little bit complicated but I would try to handle this request/response mechanism on the higher layer than message is sent through websocket.
Btw to se